# Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter: because no repositories are defined

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multibuild project and I am currently just setting it up. Each module naturally each has a `gradle.build` file that only contains the following:

```
dependencies {

}
```

In the main `build.gradle` file I have want is needed for every module. However when I do a `gradle build` I get a error saying:

> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter: because no repositories
>   are defined.   Required by:
>         project :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

sourceSets.all { ext.purpose = null }

// Everything in subprojects are applied to all modules
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'


    test {
        useTestNG()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

        beforeTest { descriptor ->
            logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
        }

        // listen to standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s)
        onOutput { descriptor, event ->
            logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Advice

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've defined repositories for subprojects only, but you have to define it in the root project too, because you have a `dependencies` block there:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

In your case you can do it by declaring `repositories` once more out of the `subprojects` closure:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

subprojects {
   ...
}
```

Or you can define it for all projects:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}
```

in that case, you don't need o declare it in `subprojects` closure

Answer (score 1):

I fixed in Intellij IDEA with these steps.

1. Go to Settings->Gradle
2. Under 'Use Gradle from' provide the correct version of Gradle
3. Gradle JVM I selected as local JAVA_HOME