# Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy, spring-framework-beans

I'm very new to grails and therefore I'm trying to do the following tutorial with IntelliJ: https://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html
After I cloned the repository, the README is asking me to run the following command:
gradle publishGuide
But I get the following error:

```
sam@sam-USMC:~/IdeaProjects/creating-your-first-grails-app$ gradle publishGuide
Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.9.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :complete
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/sam/IdeaProjects/creating-your-first-grails-app/complete/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':complete'.
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each([Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Line 19 of the build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: It looks `because no repositories are defined.` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter: because no repositories are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651374/cannot-resolve-external-dependency-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-starter)